# Open and display a file within a python script in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess, python-os

I'd like to open/display an excel file that I'm saving as part of python processing within the python script.

The save portion of the code works fine (ie, it saves successfully, and I'm open and view from a Nautilus window), but attempting to open programmatically throws errors no matter how I attempt it.

I've been using the `Popen` method within the subprocess package:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen('./temp/testtest.xlsx')
```

Gives:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './temp/testtest.xlsx'
```

I subsequently tried changing file permissions:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen

os.chmod('./temp/testtest.xlsx',0o777)
Popen('./temp/testtest.xlsx')
```

Which gave:

```
Out[127]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x7faeb22a4b00>invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error
```

And against better judgement tried running as shell:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen('./temp/testtest.xlsx', shell=True)
```

Which gave:

```
invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error 
Out[129]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x7faeb22a46a0>
```

I also tried it with the file saved in a different directory with similar errors.  If it matters, I'm using the `openpyxl` module to create and save the excel file, but I have the same issues even if it's an excel file I created manually.

Comment: The argument to `Popen()` needs to be a command line that you can type in the Terminal.

Comment: How would you open the file from the Terminal?

Comment: not sure I follow...everything I'd seen suggested `Popen()` was the Linux analog to `os.startfile()` on Windows, and was appropriate to be used within a python script.  I'm not sure how I'd open the file in terminal--directory is as above and it's an excel file if you know of a way

Comment: It executes shell commands. You need a program that takes the filename as an argument. `Popen(["programname", "temp/testtest.xlsx"])`. There's no standard Linux command for this, it depends on what application you're using (e.g. OpenOffice, LibreOffice). https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/opening-file-with-xls-on-linux-shell-prompt-210569/ suggests `oocalc` if you're using OpenOffice.

Comment: @Barmar, interesting, guess I misunderstood...looks like the following works (`localc` for LibreOffice):  `f = './temp/' + filename
    Popen(['localc', f])`.  If you want to create an answer that incorporates it for points, feel free.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Look at `xdg-open` command which redirect file to associated program (in current user graphical desktop environment). [Man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `Popen()` needs to be a shell command to open the file. If you're using LibreOffice, the program is `localc`; if you're using OpenOffice it's `oocalc`.

```
from subprocess import Popen
import os
f = os.path.join('temp', filename)
Popen(['localc', f])
```

Comment: path reference above would make line 3: `f = os.path.join('./temp', filename)`

Comment: `./temp` and `temp` are the same thing, since names are interpreted relative to `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You have Many options here. You could install libreoffice, this is an open source office suite and is fairly decent you should be able to open that file directly with `ooffice —-calc “filename”`.  If you really want to stay with python  You could save the data to a .csv file, and pythons anaconda distribution has pandas library and you could read the .csv into a data frame fairly easily. `import pandas as pd` Then
`pd.read_csv(“File_name.csv”)` returns to you a dataframe, but remember to `import os` and `os.chdir(r“/path/to/data”)`.
 From that point pandas lets you easily access the data for plotting or manipulation.

Here is all the functionality of a data frame and see if it meets your fancy.

[Python Pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html)

Comment: Thanks.  The question was about opening/viewing a created xls/csv file within a python script, not about reading data into python for manipulation